# MySQL Select from beginning until row = string

Tags: mysql, sql

Having this table:

```
+----+-------+---------+-----+
| id | group | name    | age |
+----+-------+---------+-----+
| 1  | a     | John    | 11  |
+----+-------+---------+-----+
| 2  | a     | Rachel  | 12  |
+----+-------+---------+-----+
| 3  | a     | Sarah   | 11  |
+----+-------+---------+-----+
| 4  | a     | Joe     | 14  |
+----+-------+---------+-----+
| 5  | b     | Richard | 13  |
+----+-------+---------+-----+
| 6  | b     | Zoe     | 12  |
+----+-------+---------+-----+
```

I want to write a query so I get all values from the **beginning** of the table (`id = 1`) until `group = 'b'`, so I get a table like this:

```
+----+-------+--------+-----+
| id | group | name   | age |
+----+-------+--------+-----+
| 1  | a     | John   | 11  |
+----+-------+--------+-----+
| 2  | a     | Rachel | 12  |
+----+-------+--------+-----+
| 3  | a     | Sarah  | 11  |
+----+-------+--------+-----+
| 4  | a     | Joe    | 14  |
+----+-------+--------+-----+
```

Can anyone help me? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: you can't "abort" a query like that. that's not how sql works. you could try stuff like `where group < 'b'`, but that'd only work if your groups are sortable in that sort of way.

Comment: maybe something, select all unique groups, get the first one, select all table where group = first one.. all in the same query :)

Comment: not really. what if there's a `id=5/group=b` followed by `id=6/group=a`? SQL deals with sets, it's not a spreadsheet.

Comment: That's right if I didn't wanted always a selection from the beginning. If there is id=1/group=a, id=5/group=b and id=6/group=a, I still want the firsts "group=a". So, with unique results I could get id=1/group=a, id=5/group=b and didn't receive any information about that id=6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would do a query like this:

```
select tt.*
from thistable tt
where tt.id < (select min(tt2.id) from thistable tt2 where tt2.`group` = 'b');
```

Note that `group` is a lousy name for a column name because it is a reserved word.

Comment: Perfect! group was a lousy name for example proposes :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the group values and want to get the first one you can use user defined variables or in simple words you can use rank query

```
select `id`, `group`, `name`, `age`
from (
select t.* ,
@r:= case when @g = t.`group` then @r else @r+1 end `row`,
@g:=t.`group`
from  t
cross join(select @g:='',@r:=0) t1
order by t.id , t.`group`
  ) t2
where `row` = 1
```

### [`Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4148c4/2)

Note i have ordered result using id column  of the table so if you don't have the group records in series then change order by to

```
 order by  t.`group`
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want only a the sql query will look like this

```
 Select * from myTable where group='a';
```

Comment: the problem is that, firstly, I need to know that the first group is = 'a'